# NHibernate Query help, query a child collection's child value

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have a Mapping Object listed as follows

```
Person
|- List of Countries 
|  |- Person ID
|  |- Country ID
|  |- List of States
|  |   |- State ID
```

Now I need to write a query that returns all persons that have the stateID of 2

How would you return it through a Query call in nhibernate?

session.Query().Where(t=>t.Countries.States.ID == 2) is what I am looking to do or end up with but not sure how to get it done with the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with linq as following

```
var persons = (from person in session.Query<Person>()
               from country in person.Countires
               from state in country.States
               where state.ID == 2
               select person).ToList()
```